# Using Spring @PropertySource in a Maven submodule

Tags: java, spring, maven, resources, pom.xml

In a Spring-boot application, I was having a single module and I was able to inject a configuration file, e.g. "my.properties", that was located in `src/main/resources` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("/my.properties")
public class MyConf{
}
```

Everything was ok, but then I created submodules and now I moved that configuration file in a submodule. When I start the main application I gedt the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.myapp.MainApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/home/jeanvaljean/workspace/mainmodule/secondarymodule/my.properties]
```

As I see, I can solve the issue by writing

```
@PropertySource("/src/main/resources/my.properties")
```

Doing this, the path is correct and the file can be loaded.

Anyway, that is an horrible solution, and I'm pretty sure that there is a more elegant and flexible alternative. Any solution?

Comment: Can you try changing the code to `@PropertySource("classpath:/my.properties")`? Are you getting this error when running maven from the command line or inside and IDE?

Comment: Hey, this solved the problem. Can you explain why in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring has a few different implementations of how to find a resource. By using the prefix `classpath:` you are telling Spring to search for the resource in all the classpath, rather than in the classes that are bundled with your application.

Depending on the ApplicationContenxt, Spring will use a different default Resource class. It looks like in your case, Spring was instantiating a `FileSystemResource`, which only finds files available on the filesystem with either relative or absolute paths (but not inside jars!). My rule of thumb is to never prefix something if it's in the same module/component/jar, and always prefix it with `classpath:` if I know it's in a different module/component/jar (some people get mad at this :).

You can read a more in the [Spring Documentation - Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html)